# How can I create a JSlider that allows non-integer values?

Tags: java, matlab, swing, jslider

I am currently creating a Java Swing `JSlider` in a MATLAB UI.  My slider's min and max values are 0.0 and 10.0, respectively.  I have noticed that the slider's pointer/caret/diamond snaps to integer values only.  That is, it is impossible to set the slider to a value of 5.5, for example.  This behavior is not particularly desirable for my application.

Here is my code as it stands:

```
hFig = figure(1);
hC = uicomponent('style','javax.swing.jslider','position',[10 10 400 200]);
hC.JavaComponent.setPaintLabels(true);
hC.JavaComponent.setPaintTicks(true);
hC.JavaComponent.setMinimum(0);
hC.JavaComponent.setMaximum(10);
hC.JavaComponent.setValue(5);
hC.JavaComponent.setMajorTickSpacing(2);
hC.JavaComponent.setMinorTickSpacing(1);
hC.JavaComponent.SnapToTicks(false);
```

`hC.JavaComponent` is a reference to the actual Java slider object.  The function `uicomponent()` is used to instantiate Java Swing objects in a MATLAB figure.  Since I'm working with the Java object directly, my instinct is that the fact that I'm working in MATLAB is not super important, but I could be wrong.

My questions are thus:

1. How can create a slider that allows for decimal values?
2. If (1) is not feasible, is there a better control I should be using instead of slider?

Comment: Can you slide from 0 to 1000 and divide by 100?

Comment: *"is there a better control I should be using instead of slider?"* A `JSpinner` can use a [`SpinnerNumberModel`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/swing/SpinnerNumberModel.html#SpinnerNumberModel-double-double-double-double-) with double values.

Comment: @Yunnosch, I could, but I was hoping to avoid tricks like that.  It's a good suggestion though.

Comment: @AndrewThompson, I'll take a look at JSpinners, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with an answer that mostly suits what I'm trying to do.  It is similar to the scaling idea that was suggested earlier:

```
function hC = createDecimalSlider(hFig, resolution, position, min, max, value, majorTickSpace, minorTickSpace)
    factor = 1/resolution;

    sMin = min*factor;
    sMax = max*factor;
    sValue = value*factor;
    sMajorTick = majorTickSpace*factor;
    sMinorTick = minorTickSpace*factor;

    hC = uicomponent(hFig, 'style','javax.swing.jslider','position',position);
    hC.JavaComponent.setPaintLabels(true);
    hC.JavaComponent.setPaintTicks(true);
    hC.JavaComponent.setMinimum(sMin);
    hC.JavaComponent.setMaximum(sMax);
    hC.JavaComponent.setValue(sValue);
    hC.JavaComponent.setMajorTickSpacing(sMajorTick);
    hC.JavaComponent.setMinorTickSpacing(sMinorTick);
    hC.JavaComponent.setExtent(0);
    hC.JavaComponent.SnapToTicks(false);

    fH = @(src,evt) setUD(src,evt, hC, factor);
    hC.JavaComponent.StateChangedCallback = fH;
    fH(hC.JavaComponent,[]);

    labels = java.util.Hashtable();
    for(tick = sMin:sMajorTick:sMax)
        num = tick/factor;
        str = num2str(num);
        labels.put(cast(tick,'int32'), javax.swing.JLabel(str));
    end
    hC.JavaComponent.setLabelTable(labels);
end

function setUD(hjSlider,~, hC, factor)
    hC.UserData = hjSlider.getValue()/factor;
end
```

The function is called, and the slider created, like so:

```
hFig = figure(1);
hC = createDecimalSlider(hFig, 1E-6, [10 10 400 50], 0,10,5.005,1,0.25);
```

And the value is retrieved like so:

```
value = hC.UserData;
```

It's not a super elegant solution to the problem, but hopefully it will help others out too.